# How to give action present in custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a custom cell (in ios via xib interface builder) which is having four buttons and I want to give an action (for calling some method/function) to each of them.

What can I do?

The case is I don't know how many rows are there in table but each cell having a structure as described above.

Comment: do you have a custom class for the cell you have created in the xib file?

Answer (score 0):

In the custom cell's class just create the IBAction methods you want to call and then from each button in Interface Builder link the button's action to the methods you created.

Comment: why should create methods for each of the buttons..?

Comment: I dont understand what you're asking. If you are asking me if you need a method for each button only you know what you want to do with the buttons actions at the moment. Do you need for separate methods?

Comment: i mean, why don't use a single method for all the button as the action methods?

Comment: Good question, yes you can link all the buttons to one method.

Comment: That is what i meant, fine

Comment: If you need any more help ask, and don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy it resolves your problem :)